# How to have the same length for all my widget

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a problem, I made a interface with entry, combobox and text and to get something beautiful to watch I want that: all the widgets have the same length.

But it doesn't work. I made an event (you can see under the line codes) but there is always a little offset. I try to make disappear this offset with `+2` or `+5` but doesn't work.

I use a `.grid()` to place widget.

What can I do in order to have all my widget have the same length?

line code for all the widget have the same length

```
    """
        Permet de modifier la taille de la colonne avec les médicaments1...
        les 4 variables sont utilisées pour eviter l'erreur avec la fonction trace
    """
    longeur_medoc_1 = len(self.entry_medicament_1.get())
    longeur_medoc_2 = len(self.entry_medicament_2.get())
    longeur_classe_atc_1 = len(self.te_classe_atc_medicament_1.get())
    longeur_classe_atc_2 = len(self.te_classe_atc_medicament_2.get())
    longeur = [longeur_medoc_1, longeur_medoc_2, longeur_classe_atc_1, longeur_classe_atc_2]
    longeur_max = max(longeur)
    if longeur_max < 30: longeur_max = 30
    self.description_probleme['width'] = longeur_max
    self.entry_medicament_1['width'] = longeur_max + 2
    self.classe_atc_medicament_1['width'] = longeur_max + 2
    self.entry_medicament_2['width'] = longeur_max + 2
    self.classe_atc_medicament_2['width'] = longeur_max + 2
    self.entry_date_contact_medecin['width'] = longeur_max
    self.retour_medecin['width'] = longeur_max + 5
    self.devenir_intervention['width'] = longeur_max + 2
```

[image]

Comment: Could you post a minimal example?

Comment: I had a picture in the post

Comment: where do you use `.grid()` ? I don't see it in your code? `grid()` has options which can change widget size: `sticky=...`, `padx=...`, `pady=...`, `ipadx=...`, `ipady=...`. See doc on effbot.org [grid](https://effbot.org/tkinterbook/grid.htm)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`grid()` has option `sticky=` which you can you use to resize widgets.

Using `sticky="we"` you can resize `west-east` which means `left-right`

---

Without `sticky="we"`

[image]

With `sticky="we"`

[image]

```
import tkinter as tk
        
root = tk.Tk()

label = tk.Label(root, text='Input', bg='red')
label.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='we')

button = tk.Text(root)
button.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky='we')

entry = tk.Entry(root)
entry.grid(row=2, column=0, sticky='we')

button = tk.Button(root, text='OK')
button.grid(row=3, column=0, sticky='we')

root.mainloop()
```

---

It has also `padx`, `pady`, `ipadx`, `ipady` to add margines.

Doc on effbot.org: [grid()](https://effbot.org/tkinterbook/grid.htm)